# Create empty SQL table from existing table in Azure

Tags: sql, azure

I would like to create a new empty table by copying the structure of an existing table without copying any of the records. I am using SQL Azure.

Attempt 1:

```
SELECT * INTO newTable
FROM oldTable
WHERE 1 = 0
```

Returns error:

```
Msg 40510, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Statement 'SELECT INTO' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

Attempt 2:

```
CREATE TABLE newTable
AS (SELECT * FROM oldTable WHERE 1=0)
```

Returns error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

Third time lucky? Have I missed something obvious, I am out of ideas.

**UPDATE:**
In the end I performed this procedure:

- Added Azure table as linked table in Access mdb
- Copied structure-only to local table
- Renamed table
- Exported to Azure using 'SQL Server Import and Export Wizard'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen SELECT INTO isn't supported in Azure SQL Database.  If the destination table already exists, then you can use INSERT INTO to populate it.  See Kevin Yu's post on that: http://blog.kevinyu.org/2012/06/workaround-for-select-into-in-sql-azure.html.

I believe the issue of why SELECT INTO isn't supported is because every table in SQL Azure must have a clustered index.  The SELECT INTO syntax would produce a table without a clustered index.

This is an open connect issue for this at: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/776409/add-select-into-to-sql-azure

I do not believe there is a good way to do this without first creating the destination table with a clustered index defined.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Azure requires that all tables have clustered indexes therefore you can't simply clone table structure without creating indexes.